# `ldapadd` error while adding user

Tags: linux, openldap

While adding a new test entry to ldap server, I get this error:

```
ldapadd -f /root/users.ldif -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=airwidesolutions,dc=com" -w sid

adding new entry "cn=Jack Wallen,ou=people,dc=wallen,dc=local"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

However I've checked my ldap connection is fine:

```
ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '(objectclass=*)' namingContexts
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> with scope baseObject
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: namingContexts
#

#
dn:
namingContexts: dc=airwidesolutions,dc=com

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

My slapd.conf file is defined with these parameters:

```
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=airwidesolutions,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=airwidesolutions,dc=com"
rootpw {SSHA}eBnmKHFGIlk8vp+M7c2xJ2Fha+2I/MP9 <-- encrypted form of sid
```

My users.ldif:

```
# USER ENTRY
dn: cn=Jack Wallen,ou=people,dc=wallen,dc=local
cn: Jack Wallen
objectClass: person
sn: Wallen
```

What does the error actually signify. Also I'm new to LDAP. Kindly let me know, how to debug such errors in future. i.e which are the files to check for detailed error logs to debug OPENLDAP related errors.

Kindly note I've installed openldap-2.4.35 tar file on Redhat Linux 5.6. thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/469355/no-global-superior-knowledge-while-adding-a-country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the entry `ou=people,dc=wallen,dc=local` is missing. Have you checked with an LDAP Browser if it exists?

You can only add leafs to an LDAP tree, every knot above must be explicitly created previously.